# my ground truth is a series of gray scale images

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I aim at trainig a U-Net whereby my ground truth are grey scales images (240,240,1) associated with a collection of input medical images MRI T1/T2/T1Contrast/FLAIR (240,240,4). I wonder how to configure the last layer of my unet (softmax? sigmoid?), and how to make the model understand that the grey scale values of the ground truth are to be used to calculate the loss. The last layer should deliver e.g. 256 grey levels (?) ... can I consider my problem as a segmentation problem with 256 labels??

Answer (score 0):

You will want either a 'linear' activation if your groundtruth is scaled 0 to 255, or no activation (None) if you scale it 0 to 1.

And no this is not a segmentation problem, this is a regression problem, which means you will need to use regression losses. You can start with mean-squared error. Check out the regression losses in the Keras documentation.

Comment: HI @jblugagne thanks for commenting - it is common practice to normalize input data in the range (0,1) but activation is necessary for the NN to learn I would say - it should be linear, e.g. relu in the hidden layers, but at the output? sigmoid or also relu? for regression losses I guess MSE will serve well

Comment: You can use a relu on your output layer but you can also use no activation layer.